# Detecting HTML5 Geolocation Method?

Tags: html, geolocation

Is there a way to catch which method is currently being used by the device when geolocation (watchPosition) is called? i.e. if the position comes from GPS data or some sort of trangulating or ip.. Can't seem to find anything in the position object in the callback..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I know, you can't get the source. The information provided came in my experimentation nowhere close to my location (it thought I was 100km away).

What you do get, is information how accurate the lat/long is. Combine that with altitudeAccuracy [outlined in the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/CR-geolocation-API-20100907/#position) and you can assume which service (GPS, WLAN, etc.) gave you that information.

Further, you would then use something like the [Open Geo DB](http://opengeodb.org/wiki/OpenGeoDB) to nail-down in which city the user is.

Comment: you are absolutely correct! It delivers the lat/long. I updated my answer!